# Excel Python Read File

Tags: python, excel

I am having trouble receiving the correct output to the code listed below. I separated it using---------. My goal is to read data from an excel sheet where it matches the year and location and prints out the result. That is working. My next step is trying to print out
variables "from", "to", "maxx", "min" based off just the location. For some reason, it is not outputting anything. I have attached my excel sheet as a picture to give an idea of what I am trying to do. Also is there a way to store a variable into a string. I am trying to implement a for loop for this function, and it only allows string values. listed directly below. It is the third value within parenthesis ' '[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBA2P.jpg)   [SAMPLE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svnkm.jpg)

```
psspy.two_winding_chng_4(var1,var2,'1',[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, var3, var4,_f,_f,_f],[])


import os, sys
import csv



LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\Data_2017.csv' # CSV File  to Read
# read the entire CSV into Python.
# CSV has columns starting with Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,location
data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))
mydict = {}
for row in data:
    year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,location = row[0:6]


#If this is a year not seen before, add it to the dictionary
if year not in mydict:
    mydict[year] = {}

busses_in_year = mydict[year]
if location not in busses_in_year:
     busses_in_year[location] = []


#Add the bus to the list of busses that stop at this location
busses_in_year[location].append((busnum,busname,scaled_power))




year = raw_input("Please Select Year of Study: ")
print("\n")

commands = ["Millwood-Buchanan", "Astoria-East-Corona", "Bronx", "DUNWOODIE-North-Sherman_Creek",
        "Vernon", "Greenwood-StatenIsland","West_49th","East_13th","Staten_Island","East_River",
        "East_View","DUNWOODIE-SOUTH","Corona-Jamaica","Astoria-East-Corona-Jamaica",
        "Astoria-West-Queensbridge-Vernon","Astoria-West-Queensbridge"]
max_columns = 50

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    stars_amount = max(max_columns - len(commands), 0)
    row = "# {} {}({})".format(commands, "." * stars_amount, index + 1)
    print(row)

    location=raw_input(" \n The list above show the TLA Pockets as well as the ID numbers assigned to them ()\n\n Please enter the ID #: ")
print("\n")



if year in mydict and location in mydict[year]:  
     busses_in_year = mydict[year]
     print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
     print("\n")


for busnum,busname,scaled_power in busses_in_year[location]:
    scaled_power= float(scaled_power)
    busnum = int(busnum)
    print('Bus #: %d\t' % busnum ,'Area Station: %s\t'% busname,'New Load Total: %d MW\t' % scaled_power)
```

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
if location in mydict:

     for row in data:
         location,fromm,to,digit,maxx,minn=row[6:12]


fromm_in_location = mydict[location]
if location not in fromm_in_location:
     fromm_in_location=[]

fromm_in_location[location].append((fromm,to,digit,maxx,minn))

fromm_in_location=mydict[location]

for fromm,to,digit,maxx,minn in fromm_in_location[location]:
    maxx= float(maxx)
    minn=float(minn)
    fromm = int(fromm)
    to=int(to)
    print('From #: %d\t' % fromm ,'To: %d\t'% to,'VMAX: %d \t' % maxx, 'VMIN: %d\t' %minn)
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Hey, Mark! I'm having trouble following your question... Maybe you can reformat the question as: This is what I have. This is what I Tried. this is the output I need. From the looks of it though `pandas` is a library you may want to get familiar with

Comment: My goal is trying to read variables(fromm, to, maxx, minn) based off the location criteria. If I were to select # 1, I want the values in the row to be read off. I am trying to avoid using two criteria because I would have to copy and paste data numerous times. But since data is same thing for every year, I want to it to read just location. But if data were to different for a particular year, I would like to also know how to do that as well

Comment: Hmm.. still a little lost. Try editing your question. Try to include a piece of sample data, sample input, and sample output

Comment: Please Select Year: 1

Comment: edit it in the question and not on the comments section - this will help others who come here try and solve your need

Comment: I attached sample output

Comment: Are the `if`s not in the loop on purpose? (in the first `for` loop). You overwrite that data in each iteration without ever using it.

Comment: I am not sure what I did. I just took a guess